# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ke^{-x}\ln(xe^{-x})dx$

Tags: integration

Investigating $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ke^{-x}\ln(xe^{-x})dx=g(k)$

Setting k=0

$g(0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln(xe^{-x})dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln(x)dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}-xe^{-x}dx=I+J$ respectively

$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln(x)dx$ ; integrating by parts

$u=\ln(x) \rightarrow du={1\over x}dx$

$dv=e^{-x} \rightarrow v=-e^{-x}$

$I=\left.-e^{-x}\ln(x)\right|_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}\over x}dx$; this is not making any sense to me, I used wolfram integrator to see if there is an answer.

Wolfram integrator gives $I=-\gamma$

$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx$, integrating by parts

$u=x \rightarrow du=dx$

$dv=e^{-x} \rightarrow v=-e^{-x}$

$J=\left.-xe^{-x}\right|_{0}^{\infty}\left.-e^{-x}\right|_{0}^{\infty}=1$

So finally $g(0)=-\gamma-1$

Anyway this process seem lengthy for me, so common sense said use the wolfram integrator to find a few more values of g(k).

Here are a few of g(k)

$-g(0)=\gamma+1$

$-g(1)=\gamma+1$

$-g(2)=2\gamma+3$

$-g(3)=6\gamma+13$

$-g(4)=24\gamma+70$

$1,1,2,6,24$ are obvious, they are n! Factorial.

As for $1,1,3,13,70$ They are not obvious at first, but it takes time to figured them out. Something to do with porch-hammer.

Only consider the coefficients of x

$(x)_0=1 \rightarrow \color{blue}{1}=1$

$(x)_1=x \rightarrow \color{blue}{1}=1$

$(x)_2=x(1+x)=x^2+x \rightarrow \color{blue}{1}(1)+\color{blue}{1}(2)=3$

$(x)_3=x(1+x)(2+x)=x^3+3x^2+2x \rightarrow \color{blue}{1}(1)+\color{blue}{3}(2)+\color{blue}{2}(3)=13$

$(x)_4=x(1+x)(2+x)(3+x)=x^4+6x^3+11x^2+6x \rightarrow \color{blue}{1}(1)+\color{blue}{6}(2)+\color{blue}{11}(3)+\color{blue}{6}(4)=70$

And so on...

This is the farthest I understood this integral produce.

Can somebody show me how this integral is evaluated in the normal way

$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ke^{-x}\ln(xe^{-x})dx=g(k)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{k}e^{-x}\log\left(xe^{-x}\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{k}e^{-x}\log\left(x\right)dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{k+1}e^{-x}dx=I+J
 $$ say. Note that if $k>-1
 $ $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{k}e^{-x}dx=\Gamma\left(k+1\right)
 $$ so $$\frac{d}{dk}\Gamma\left(k+1\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{k}e^{-x}\log\left(x\right)dx=I
 $$ but it is well known that the derivative of the Gamma function can be written in terms of the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) $$\frac{d}{dk}\Gamma\left(k+1\right)=\Gamma\left(k+1\right)\psi\left(k+1\right)
 $$ and trivially $$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{k+1}e^{-x}dx=\Gamma\left(k+2\right)
 $$ so $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{k}e^{-x}\log\left(xe^{-x}\right)dx=\Gamma\left(k+1\right)\psi\left(k+1\right)-\Gamma\left(k+2\right)
 $$ $$=\Gamma\left(k+1\right)\left(\psi\left(k+1\right)-\left(k+1\right)\right),\, k>-1$$ where the last identity follows from the [Gamma's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).